# How to recover password if i forget encryption key in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter 3 and PHP 5.6

I have created a user with password `encode()` and `decode()` method with my encryption key,
one of my team members changed the encryption key,
now I unable to decrypt password created by the previous encryption key,
pls help me how to decrypt

`autoload.php`

```
     $autoload['libraries'] = array( 'database', 'session', 'form_validation', 'upload', 'encrypt', 'cart','pagination' );
```

`usercontroller`

```
   $key                    = $this->config->item( 'encryption_key' );
   $arr[ 'decrpyt' ]   = $this->encrypt->decode( $vaue->password, $key );
```

Comment: Please use forgot password

Comment: I think this is not a solution, i need to recover old password, is there any  possible way available pls tell me

Answer (score 0):

CI 3 usually use MD5. Encrypt the password on https://www.md5online.org/md5-encrypt.html and replace your password in database. (Backup your prev password first.)